# Split after some value

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I have this input:

> The Title #14 first 324.36 USD Second-GUY 261 USD Third33 101 USD

and I want to split that string to save in db.

So `The title #14` is a title and it might be 1 word or many but all of them has `#` and some int value (it might be `#2222` as well)

and after that title I want to get `first` and `324.36`, `Second-GUY` and `261` etc. How can I do that?

I know about split and so I can `input.Split('#')` but I don't know what to do with that int.

on the second side I'll split with `USD`

first value I want to be: `The Title #14`

second: `first 324.36`

third: `Second-GUY 261`

as it is in image:

[image]

Comment: You should also consider regex

Comment: @maccettura can you show me a way how to do that? for now I have no experience with regex

Comment: To be clear, the title-column's content is `The Title #14` the first field's content is: `324.36 USD`, the second: `GUY 261 USD`, third: `33 101 USD`? So 4 columns?

Comment: @TimSchmelter first is: `The Title #14`
second: `first 324.36`
third: `Second-GUY 261` etc.

Comment: So you dont care about the `USD` part?

Comment: yeah i don't. I want to get rid of them

Comment: The requirements for a regex are unclear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: you can remove  `for a regex` from that sentence

Comment: Maybe it would help if you'd show your datamodel and also the expected parameters

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm getting string like that. and I want to write that value in db like this: http://prntscr.com/fq2aca

Comment: why not split on space, and read up to the word "first". And so on?

Comment: @barlop Because I have no idea how many word will be in title. All I know is that it contains # and some int value

Comment: @gsiradze so won't they all , for title, have the last value of #123 so you can split on space and read up to that for the title. As a start you could read up to the field that starts with # Then you have the title. Then you could know what each field is after that unless others also have spaces.

Comment: store the index position of the #. find the indexOf the first space after the hash by using indexOf with a start position of where the hash is located. store the substring of (0, position of the space after the hash) that's the title. Store to a second string the substring of pos+1) that's the rest. Split the rest on the space. Loop through the array from the split and ignore where the element == "USD".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could help with the solution

```
string lsInput = "The Title #14 first 324.36 USD Second-GUY 261 USD Third33 101 USD";
var loMatch = Regex.Match(lsInput, @"(?<title>.*#\d+)\s(?<parts>.*)");
string lsTitle = loMatch.Groups["title"].Value; //The Title #14
var loParts = loMatch.Groups["parts"].Value.Split(new string[] { "USD" },  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
   Select(item => item.Trim()).ToList();
```

Output loParts:

```
Count = 3
[0]: "first 324.36"
[1]: "Second-GUY 261"
[2]: "Third33 101"
```

Comment: Split loParts on "USD" and this is the best solution.

Comment: Made a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4ysRz5) showing the split on USD

Comment: @maccettura Yes thats right if split on USD then you have your output.

Answer (score -1):

[Regex Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) is very suitable for a task like that, write a pattern and let `Regex` class to do the job.
 here is an example that shows how to use Regex based on your string.
 please read my comments inside the example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Target = "The Title #14 first 324.36 USD Second-GUY 261 USD Third33 101 USD";
    var value = string.Empty;
    var pattern = "(The Title) ([#]{1})([0-9]{1,500})";

    if (Example(Target,pattern, ref value) == true) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(value); // output: The Title #14
    }

    pattern = "(first) ([0-9]{1,500}(.)[0-9]{1,500})";

    if (Example(Target, pattern, ref value) == true) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(value); // output: first 324.36, if you want only the number one way is to replace  MessageBox.Show(value); to MessageBox.Show(value.Replace("first",""));
    }

    pattern = "(Second-GUY) ([0-9]{1,500}(.)[0-9]{1,500})";

    if (Example(Target, pattern, ref value) == true) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(value); // output: Second-GUY 261, if you want only the number one way is to replace  MessageBox.Show(value); to MessageBox.Show(value.Replace("Second-GUY",""));
    }
}

private bool Example(string Target,string pattern, ref string value)
{

    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);
    bool ismatched = reg.IsMatch(Target);

    if (ismatched)
    {
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = reg.Match(Target);
        value = match.Value;
    }

    return ismatched;
}
```